# translate mysql "create table" to postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to translate "create table" from mySQL to postgreSQL:

mySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pets (
id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30),
birth_date DATE,
type_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
owner_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
INDEX(name),
FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owners(id),
FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES types(id)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

It works.

postgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pets (
                                      id integer(4) NOT NULL,
                                      CONSTRAINT LABEL_ID PRIMARY KEY(id),
                                      name varchar(30),
                                      birth_date date,
                                      type_id integer(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                                      owner_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                                      INDEX(name),
                                      CONSTRAINT owners(id) FOREIGN KEY(owner_id),
                                      CONSTRAINT TYPES (id) FOREIGN KEY(type_id));
```

For postgreSQL it doesn't work.

Why?

Comment: *For postgreSQL it doesn't work. Why?* Because none server will understand the syntax which you have imagined for it.

Answer (score 2):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) `integer` doesn't take a "length" parameter. Also on that page it's clearly visible that there is no "unsigned" modifier for integers. Indexes are defined using the [`create index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) statement, not using an "index option" inside the [create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) statement.

And the foreign key declaration needs a referenced table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pets (
  id integer NOT NULL generated always as identity,
  CONSTRAINT LABEL_ID PRIMARY KEY(id),
  name varchar(30),
  birth_date date,
  type_id integer NOT NULL,
  owner_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(owner_id) references owners (id),
  FOREIGN KEY(type_id) references TYPES (id) 
);

create index on pets (name);
```